# How can I use motion graphics templates created in Adobe AE CC 2018 in older software (CC 2017, CS 6)?

Tags: cs6, adobe-after-effects, adobe-creative-suite, adobe-premiere

**First of all:** why would somebody break backwards compatibility or at least don't offer a way to downgrade project files or uses an open file format at last?

**Secondly:** I've made a lower third template in AE 2018 for my client, unfortunately they only work with Premiere Pro 2017 (or lower) without the new motion graphics feature. I, on the other hand, can only use the current Adobe Suite. Now I'm looking for a way to make my template compatible without the need to rebuild the whole project. I even can't open an ordinary Premiere project in an older version... why Adobe, why?

**I'd be glad if somebody could offer workflow!**

Comment: The first answer is for Adobe to answer so useless to ask here, but I can tell you already: it's how they make money. I'd remove from the question it since it's just ranting.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround.

If you have a CC subscription, you can download and install older versions of the software from the Creative Cloud desktop app. Just enable "Show older apps" in the preferences. Then you can choose "other versions" from the dropdown in the main apps page.

[image]

Comment: I only have the software provided by my company via prebuild packages, this means, I can't install older apps. Nevertheless, thanks for you effort!

Comment: @ANewGuest You might want to check that out with your IT department.  If it's simply a case of getting someone with admin privileges to install the software for you, then this could still be a workable option.

Comment: @A New Guest, you have the answer, either you look for implement it, or you don't. There is no workarround.